# How to join MySQL tables?

Tags: mysql

I basically have two tables:

```
A(id int, name varchar(10), info varchar(10))
B(id int, item varchar(10))

A
1 A Hello
2 B World
3 C Foo

B
1 apple
1 orange
1 hammer
2 glass
2 cup
```

Note that C doesn't have any items. I want to join the two tables to get this:

```
1 A Hello apple|orange|hammer
2 B World glass|cup
3 C Foo null
```

I am familiar with the `GROUP_CONCAT(item SEPARATOR '|')` concept but I'm not quite sure how to write the query, especially to get the row with `3 C Foo null`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mysql> SELECT a.id, a.name, a.info, group_concat(b.item SEPARATOR '|')
       FROM a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON (a.id=b.id)
       GROUP BY 1,2,3;                                                             
+------+------+-------+------------------------------------+
| id   | name | info  | group_concat(b.item separator '|') |
+------+------+-------+------------------------------------+
|    1 | A    | Hello | apple|orange|hammer                | 
|    2 | B    | World | glass|cup                          | 
|    3 | C    | Foo   | NULL                               | 
+------+------+-------+------------------------------------+
```

Outer joins explained: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Outer_joins

Comment: @Ed: LEFT OUTER JOIN is the same as LEFT JOIN

Answer (score 0):

SELECT a.id, a.name, a.info, GROUP_CONCAT( b.name
SEPARATOR  '|' ) 
FROM A AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN B AS b ON b.id = a.id
GROUP BY a.id

returns

id  name    info    group_concat(b.name SEPARATOR '|')
1   A   Hello   apple|orange|hammer
2   B   World   glass|cup
3   C   Foo NULL